# WordPress: How to display only one category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

In my design I show the category of the post in the home page. 
The problem is when I add more that one category in a post. 
How can I make so that it will display only one category.

Example: I have 3 categories A, B and C. 
I add a post in categories A and B. 
In the home page is displayed ... *Post title* in category A, B. 
I want the output to be ... *Post title* in category A.

For the category I use get_the_category_list

Comment: your question is not really clear, are you trying to display post (post titles) or categories?

Comment: Categories or more specifically only one category. If the post has 3 categories I want to display only one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

get_the_category() returns an array of all associated categories for the post. To echo out only the first category from the result set try something like:

```
<?php
   $category = get_the_category(); 
   echo $category[0]->cat_name;
?>
```

Comment: hey ply, you were helping me in another question but it was closed. What you told me didnt work. Do you have any other ideas?